# Why some outer rule came for this box?

Tags: tcolorbox

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}%
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%
\definecolor{colorthree}{cmyk}{0.16,0,0.06,0}%
\definecolor{shadestartcolor}{cmyk}{0.19,0,0.07,0.20}%

\newenvironment{defin}[1][26]{\bgroup%
\vspace{12\p@ plus3\p@ minus1\p@}%
\noindent\ignorespaces\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, colback=colorthree, frame hidden,arc=6pt,
underlay vignette={draw method=clipped, size=3mm, semi fade in=shadestartcolor, east size=1.5mm, south size=1mm}]
\begin{definition}%
}{\end{definition}\end{tcolorbox}%
\end{minipage}%
\vspace{12\p@ plus3\p@ minus1\p@}%
\egroup}%
\makeatother

\begin{defin}
This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for
test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is
for test.   
\end{defin}

\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]

Eventhough I mentioned that `frame hidden`

My actual requirement shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the border, add `boxrule=0pt` to `tcolorbox` options.

I don't understand why you need to include `tcolorbox` into an external environment and inside a `minipage`. A `tcolorbox` is by default as wide a `\textwidth`. There exist an special library for `theorems` and if you don't want to use it, command `\tcolorboxenvironment` can add `tcolorbox` aspect to any regular environment. In following code I've declared a `mydefinition` theorem to which similar tcolorbox parameters has bee applied. The result is similar with a less complex code.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}%
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%
\newtheorem{mydefinition}{Definition}%

\definecolor{colorthree}{cmyk}{0.16,0,0.06,0}%
\definecolor{shadestartcolor}{cmyk}{0.19,0,0.07,0.20}%

\tcolorboxenvironment{mydefinition}{%
enhanced, colback=colorthree, frame hidden,arc=6pt,boxrule=0pt,
underlay vignette={draw method=clipped, size=3mm, semi fade in=shadestartcolor, east size=1.5mm, south size=1mm}}

\newenvironment{defin}[1][26]{\bgroup%
\vspace{12\p@ plus3\p@ minus1\p@}%
\noindent\ignorespaces\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, colback=colorthree, frame hidden,arc=6pt,boxrule=0pt,
underlay vignette={draw method=clipped, size=3mm, semi fade in=shadestartcolor, east size=1.5mm, south size=1mm}]
\begin{definition}%
}{\end{definition}\end{tcolorbox}%
\end{minipage}%
\vspace{12\p@ plus3\p@ minus1\p@}%
\egroup}%
\makeatother

\begin{defin}
This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for
test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is
for test.   
\end{defin}

\begin{mydefinition}
This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for
test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is
for test.   
\end{mydefinition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Much thanks, such a silly mistake I did....Really thanks for correcting me....Also thanks a lot for mentioned about `\tcolorboxenvironment`, really it is helpful....